# "DELETE" function always shows "undefined" for the "params" object,I use Postman to send this http://localhost:3000/api/issues/2

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

Here is my code,

`DELETE` function always shows "undefined" for the `params"`object, when I use the Postman to send this http://localhost:3000/api/issues/2.
Not passing id 2 in the params .

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";  
import prisma from "../../../../../prisma/client";  

export async function DELETE({ params }) { 
  console.log('Params:', params); 
  const id = params?.id;
  console.log('ID:', id); 

  
  try {
    
    const issueId = await prisma.issue.findUnique({
      where: { id: parseInt(params.id) }
    });
  
    if (!issueId) return NextResponse.json({ error: "Invalid issue" }, { status: 404 });
  
    await prisma.issue.delete({
      where: { id: issueId.id },
    });
  
    return NextResponse.json({});

catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ status: "Fail" }, { status: 500 }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you define it as `DELETE(params)` without destructuring?

Comment: If you're using app router (/api/issues/[id]/route.tsx) you should be able to get the id param like this:

`export async function DELETE(request: Request, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {    const id = params.id;  ....`